# Is it better to pray at a synagogue where you feel comfortable praying, or to go where your father prays?

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

This is a common problem with guys living near or with their parents.

Do you fulfill Kibud Av Ve'aim and go to shul with your father, or is it preferred to pray at a place where you feel more spiritual and can pray with more kevanah and motivation?

Comment: As always, consult your rabbi if this is relevant to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Chamudei Daniel, cited by the [Pischei Teshuvah Yoreh Deah 240:22](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6696) says that one may pray in the shul where he will have more kavvanah. Rav Pam points out that one should take into consideration other possible ramifications before acting on this ruling. See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=tPQOX87XxaUC&lpg=PA131&ots=eM-0FJSldh&dq=chamudei%20daniel%20kibbud&pg=PA130#v=onepage&q=chamudei%20daniel%20kibbud&f=false).

Answer (score -3):

mishnah berurah 90 28 qoutes radvaz vol 3 siman 472 that it is more important to daven in a place you can have kavanah then to daven with rov am

Comment: How is this relevant?

Comment: if feeling comfortable in a minyan is more important than the halocho of rov am it would be safe to assume that having more kavanah is part of the essence of tefillah, and a father doesn't have permission to deprive his son from davening

Comment: Maybe Kivud Av > Tefila (which is comprised of Kavana > BeRov Am)

Comment: I actually don't think this answer is so bad, considering the comment. It might be wrong, and an argument supporting the downvotes has been provided, but I recommend incorporating the comment into the answer rather than deleting the answer altogether.

Comment: This answer is missing the relation between the rov am and an av. Once the relation is reconciled, this could be a great answer.